# EXCEL Sum range based on row and column criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given the Category table below:

[image: sample]

... how can I add all values in a particular category row that are in columns where the date header is <= TODAY() ?

For example, in cell B2 I want a running total of the values corresponding to the "Internet Bill" row and only columns where today (3/15) is >= the date in the column header. I highlighted these values in red just for the example.

Here's what I have so far in B2:

`=SUM(INDEX($F$2:$J$4,MATCH($A2,$E2,0),MATCH(TODAY(),$F$1:$J$1,1)))`

But it's only giving me "$45," which I understand correlates the greatest date value lesser than 3/15. I just can't get the INDEX formula to return a column_num range filtered by a comparison operator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B2 G$1:J$1 requires date format, please change J1 to your actual range.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(F$1,MATCH(A2,E:E,)-1,,,COUNTIF(G$1:J$1,"<="&TODAY())))
```

Comment: Note that the table on the left does not always line up with the table on the right (row 2 will not always be "Internet Bill" in both tables). Also, I want to be able to add new categories to both tables and have the INDEX function adapt to the new data.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have office 365, you can use the formula below

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(FILTER($B$3:$N$4,$A$3:$A$4=B7),$B$2:$N$2<=$A$1)),"Not Found")
```

[image: Sample data and result]

The formula also accounts for error supposing the data is not found

Supposing your data table is in another Sheet (Sheet 1), you can use formula below

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$3:$N$4,Sheet1!$A$3:$A$4=B2),Sheet1!$B$2:$N$2<=$A$1)),"Not Found")
```

[image: Sample 2]

Comment: Can you show me how to modify your formula so that it will work if the tables are on different sheets?

Comment: i have revised the answer, check again